# DAO: db.OpenRecordSet("Table1", dbOpenTable, 0, dbPessimistic) - what does the third argument do?

Tags: vb6, dao

Using DAO out of VB6:

```
db.OpenRecordSet("Table1", dbOpenTable, 0, dbPessimistic)
```

If the third argument is set to `0`, as in the above, what is its effect?  `0` is not a listed value for this argument in the documentation.

EDIT: What sort of recordset will be opened if `0` is given as the third argument?

Answer (score 0):

This is the `Options` argument. Passing `0` is equivalent to not passing any options at all.

Look at the [manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225802%28office.12%29.aspx) linked by d_schnell: all the constants have non-zero values.

You can also check the values directly in the VB6 IDE. Type one of the supported values in a code window, like `dbAppendOnly`. Put the cursor on the word and press `Shift+F2`. The object browser opens up, with a list of all the constants. They all have non-zero values (values are shown at the bottom of the object browser).